# MySQL Workbench - Unable to see text output results

Tags: mysql, output, mysql-workbench

I have executed a query using Execute (All or Selection) to Text but nothing is appearing in the text output pane mysql workbench 8.0.12 version.

The action output and history output both display results.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the execute was successful, it was an select and you don't see the result grid, restart the workbench. It's a bug which reappeared with version 8.

Comment: Hi Datavader. Yes I mean the query has run successfully but I'm not getting any text output despite using the 'Execute (All or Selection) to text' to run the query. I had tried to restart the workbench already.

Comment: Hi Datavader. It is a normal select command and I'm running the query via the query menu, then 'Execute (All or Selection) to text'. I am expecting a text output in the text pane but its not appearing.

Comment: Did you find a resolution ? In the output panel, text output is totally empty